# Any method to grab and use variables from a text file passed as a parameter in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a txt file named `setup.txt` that contains the following data:

```
DSN=ZXP.SOURCE
PATH=/z/zxp/20211015
SCHEMA=ZXP
URL=https://zxp-support.mybluemix.net/contest/4q21/
OUTPUT=OUTPUT(RESULT)
REPORT=q421report
```

I am able to grab the variables some help to use `declare` but the I am not able to execute commands down below in the script

```
input="$1"

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
  then
    printf "This program takes the input from a file (first argument)\n"
    exit 1
fi
if test -f "$input"; then
    echo "$input exists."
else
    echo "File $input does not exist, or is not a file"
    exit 1
fi
mapfile -t a < $1
declare "${a[@]}" 

db="$DSN"
path="$PATH"
schema="$SCHEMA"
url="$URL"
output="$OUTPUT"
report="$REPORT"

DB2="java com.ibm.db2.clp.db2"
$DB2 -tvf decrypt.sql > parse_decryption1.txt
key=$(python3 decryption.py)
sed -e 's/schema/'"${schema}"'/g;s/pass/'"${key}"'/g' drop3.sql > finaldrop4.sql
$DB2 -tvf finaldrop4.sql > raw_data.txt
python3 drop4.py ${url} > drop5output.txt
```

I get the following erros:

```
./q421drop5.sh: line 30: java: command not found
./q421drop5.sh: line 31: python3: command not found
./q421drop5.sh: line 32: sed: command not found
./q421drop5.sh: line 33: java: command not found
./q421drop5.sh: line 36: python3: command not found
./q421drop5.sh: line 37: cp: command not found
```

How can I access the variables and still be able to execute other commands below?

Comment: `PATH=/z/zxp/20211015` Choose another variable name, `PATH` already is used. To find commands.

Comment: Best to avoid upper case variables when writing shell scripts, especially when the variables are just for your script to use. In your example, you just replace the value of `PATH` , jfyi, `PATH` is where the shell looks for executables/program, that is why you can just invoke the name of that program/executable and it's not need to add the *absolute* `PATH`

Comment: The requirements for testing my scripts says the ```setup.txt``` will contain variables in that format, as in ```PATH=/z/zxp/20211015```will be contained in the setup.txt and its the actual path that may be changing